# Error in sequential execution of pop command and push command?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I used the `push` command and printed the array before using the `pop` command, but it is not applied and is gone

```
var a={
    arr:[],
    boolean:true,
    test:function(){
        if(a.boolean){
            a.arr.push(1);
            console.log(a.arr);
        }
        if(a.boolean)
            a.arr.pop();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the content of your array is evaluated only after you click the arrow to the left of the array in your console. So what you see in the console in both cases is the result **after** both `push` and `pop`, so they appear empty.

If you hover over the little `i` symbol to the right of `Array[1]`, it tells you exactly that ("Value below was evaluated just now").

Comment: It is empty even if it is not assigned to the console.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be empty? You are first pushing an item, then popping it. The result is an empty array.